# How to improve English listening at high level?

Tags: listening

I am an international student in UK, and I did get a quite high mark on IELTS listening, about 8 to 9. And I can easily understand what the professors say in the lecture, partly because I have a quite good academic level in my major and my major doesn't acquire very good English.(I am a pure math major)

However, I can't understand what my classmates are talking about after class. If they are talking to me, things become easier. But when they are making conversation as a group, I simply have no idea what they are talking about. I tried to listen Podcasts and radios, but without sub I can only understand tiny pieces of them. If I return to listen exam-based listening comprehension, they become too easy to me. Thus, I want to know what I can do to improve my listening. I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Watch soap operas.  They use simple and colloquial (everyday) language and are very easy to follow.

Comment: For me, after I used to listen to the sports broadcast, I felt my listening level increased.

Comment: Download one of the free apps online to listen to a radio station such as BBC World Service (for British English) or National Public Radio (or one of the many American talk stations) for American English.

Comment: @RonaldSole it seems to me that the OP is having difficulty in listening to colloquial/slang fast-pace speaking. All I can suggest is to go to your local cafeteria and eavesdrop. If you're feeling brave enough, ask a table if you can record their conversation emphasising that you need to practice your listening skills. They'll probably refuse and think you're weird.... tricky... ask to join parties, go to clubs, join a sports centre any place where young people gather. Beaches are a great place to hear natural speech in action.

Comment: Listen to Joe Rogan podcasts http://podcasts.joerogan.net/ He's an American English speaker. You could also try out [Howard Stern](https://www.howardstern.com/) (not everyone's cup of tea but Stern knows how to interview celebrities.) These podcasts also have videos on YouTube, visual clues are also important.

Comment: You could watch any and all sorts of television programs: sitcoms, dramas, news, cartoons (if they are speaking).   Until you get to 100.00% of understanding these programs, it means you're still learning, and so it's still a relatively productive use of time.